# In an ordered array of scalars find preceeding smaller and following larger given a number.

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array of numbers and I want to get the first numbers that are less than a specific x and then first that is greater than the same x.

```
var str = 'some random string that is kind of long',
        items = [],
        position = 10, //varies
        itemsBefore,
        itemsAfter,
        firstItemBeforePosition,
        firstItemAfterPosition; //varies

for(var i = 0, length= str.length; i < length; i++){
    if(str[i] === ' '){
        items.push(i);
    }
}

itemsBefore = items.filter(function(item){
    return item < position;
});

itemsAfter = items.filter(function(item){
    return item > position;
});

firstItemBeforePosition = itemsBefore.length > 0 ? itemsBefore[itemsBefore.length - 1] : 0;
firstItemAfterPosition = itemsAfter.length > 0 ? itemsAfter[0] : str.length;
```

Based on the JavaScript code I provided, the items array will be `[4, 11, 18, 23, 26, 31, 34]`, `firstItemBeforePosition` is 4, and `firstItemAfterPosition` is 11.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: _“Is there a better way to do this?”_ – first of all you should formulate what the _actual_ problem/task is. It seems to be not about “numbers in an array”, but the first space character in a string before and after a given position. And then of course there is a better way to do this – assuming you don’t need the actual array of numbers: Two loops, going back and forth from the position until you find a space.

Comment: Are you actually trying to get the start and end position of the word? Or are you more interested in the problem of finding the first bigger & smaller number from an array?

Comment: That's what I was struggling with too - if you want the biggest number in itemsBefore and the smallest in itemsAfter you could just use Math.max and Math.max

Comment: @CBroe well getting the space character indexes would then result in an array of numbers, right? two loops. hmm. wait thank you, i'll try that!

Comment: Do you actually _need_ that array of numbers (if so, what for?), or only the two values that you set in the last two lines of the code shown?

Comment: @CBroe come to think of it, no, I actually don't need it. I tried the two loops like you said. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way of doing it that requires less code and won't loop the entire list. It also uses a few less variables and employs more native code functions (that should be faster).

```
var str, array, length, firstItemBeforePosition, firstItemAfterPosition;

str = 'some random string that is kind of long';
length = 0;
position = 10;

array = str.split(' ');
array = array.map( function( s, i ){ length += s.length; return length+i })

array.some(function(e){
  if ( e < position ) firstItemBeforePosition = e;
  if ( e > position ) {
    firstItemAfterPosition = e;
  }
  return firstItemAfterPosition;
});
```

The some function is in Javascript as of 1.6 (ES5) and will work in IE9+. Unlike a for loop or a forEach the some method returns as soon as the callback function returns a truthy value. Since the `firstItemAfterPosition` is null when we start it's falsy and some will keep going until we assign it a value by what time it will be truthy and some will exit.

If the list of position values is really long I'd suggest looking at [binary search](http://oli.me.uk/2013/06/08/searching-javascript-arrays-with-a-binary-search/) since it will be O(log n) instead of O(n). If you have no idea what that means your problem size is probably small enough that you don't have to worry :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop should do this:

```
for(var k = 0; k < items.length; k++)
{
  if (items[k] > position)
  {
    firstItemAfterPosition = items[k];
    firstItemBeforePosition = items[k-1];
    break;
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7CZvf/1/